# How do I remove carriage returns from directory names?

Tags: rename, filenames

I created a file in Excel and ftp'd the file over to my Linux machine.  In the file were a bunch of `mkdir` commands.  Now all of the newly created directories have a carriage return at the end of them.  I can find the directories using this command:

```
find . -type d -name *$'\r'
```

but when I attempt to remove them using this command:

```
find . -type d -name *$'\r' | xargs rm-rf
```

it doesn't work - nothing gets removed.  The directories are still there and they still have carriage returns on them.

Can you help me create a command that will remove those pesky '\r's?  Thanks.

P.S.  I'm using RHEL 5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED: forgot to double escape the \r in the `sed` line

either of these should work for you

```
for i in $(find . -type d -name '*\r'); do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed -e 's/\\r//g')"; done

find . -type d -name '*\r' -exec mv "{}" "$(echo {} | sed -e 's/\\r//g')" \;
```

this will find all directories named *$\r under your currently directory

it will then `mv`(rename) them to the same name minus the \r

Comment: This worked, except I changed '*\r' to *$'\r'.  Thanks for the help.  I don't know who down-voted this answer - shame on them :)  Also, I used the second command you listed.

Comment: @FathomSavvy yeah, not sure how a working answer gets down-voted... glad to help though.

Comment: +1 for a working solution. The downvote is probably from the bash purist brigade for parsing command substitution output, this is deemed a pitfall(http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). The preferred option is to use a combination of read and find with NUL byte separators see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Comment: @ChandraRavoori that makes a sense, thanks for the tip. I edited and added quotes

Answer (score 11):

Linux's [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) command makes this easy:

```
rename $'\r' '' *
```

This replaces the first and only carriage return (`$'\r'`) by an empty string (`''`) in all file names in the current directory. Names that don't contain a carriage return are left unchanged (or you can write `rename $'\r' '' *$'\r'` to only consider files that must be renamed).

If you need to act on files in subdirectories as well:

```
shopt -s globstar
rename $'\r' '' **/*$'\r'
```

(Users of Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives: change `rename` to `rename.ul`, or change `rename $'\r' ''` to `rename 's/\r//'`.)

Alternative, using zsh's [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) function:

```
zmv $'**/*\r' "${f%?}"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `find . -type d -name *$'\r' -exec rm -rf '{}' \;`

Comment: that will remove the file itself not the '\r' from the directory name

Comment: misunderstood this **I attempt to remove them using this command**

Comment: I tried this command.  It cut off the first 6 letters of the directory name.  I got the error "No such file or directory xxx".

Comment: Actually, I think it was a combination of your solution and h3rmiller that made it work.

Comment: I think it's a reasonable interpretation that the intention was to remove the files themselves -- from the wording to the sample command being "rm -rf". The comments point out what the Answer should have -- that this answer intends to remove (forcefully, recursively) any directories whose filename ends in a carriage return.